# Firebase FCM Token Expiration

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I'm developing an Android app and it uses push notifications, my question is what happens if a user doesn't connect to the app for a long period like 3 months or even more, is it still possible to send them a push notification?

What interests me is only the expiration date of the token, I am not currently interested in dealing with all the reasons (uniinstalltion, clear data etc...) that cause the application to create a new token.

According to what is written in the documentation, the expiration date can happen after a few days, maybe a few weeks, and then we will receive a new token in onNewToken(newToken: String)
But this function is called only when the user enters the application, then he receives a new token. But what happens if the token is expired because 4 months have passed and it still hasn't entered the application so onNewToken will never send the new token to the server so what does that mean it won't receive push notifications?

So in conclusion, how to make push notifications for users who haven't logged in for a long time yet?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: onNewToken is called on the background. SaveTokenOnline() There is no need to open the app..

Comment: You can integrate onesignal as well.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Service will still be running in the background. Even, When the app is closed. When onNewToken() is called in the background. Save it saveOnlineDB(). And also in preference. If this fails retry saveOnlineDB() a few more times.

Whenever a user opens the app save session time. You can detect old users from it. Who didn't open app for a long time.

Additionally, You can integrate OneSignal. It has a lot more to offer. It is built on top of Firebase.